# "Exception: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry" error where index is truncated

Tags: mysql, indexing, unique-constraint, unique-index

I sometimes get the following error in my application log for an insert into MySQL:

```
2013/06/02 15:11:05 (Database) Exception: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry '4d9acbacc6ed7dc2733025e4b8af7be4940fe5b70338789b34caea27695860fa' for key 'hash_UNIQUE'
```

The problem with the above is that the value being indexed is being truncated to 64 characters long, but the actual column size 255 characters long.  An example of that value is: `4d9acbacc6ed7dc2733025e4b8af7be4940fe5b70338789b34caea27695860fa2b497f6cd34851657c9d3e8e8e88713d80da1a22d8654cf98622e9af3f29481d`.

The table definition is below:

```
delimiter $$

CREATE TABLE `reset` (
  `id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `identity_id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `hash` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `timestamp` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `upn` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `returnurl` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `processed` char(1) DEFAULT 'N',
  `referer` varchar(15) DEFAULT 'CPCUsociety.org',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `hash_UNIQUE` (`hash`),
  KEY `reset_upn_ndx` (`upn`),
  KEY `reset_hash_ndx` (`hash`),
  KEY `reset_timestampndx` (`timestamp`),
  KEY `idendity_id_for_key_idx` (`identity_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `idendity_id_for_key` FOREIGN KEY (`identity_id`) REFERENCES `identity` (`id`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=585 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8$$
```

How can I force MySQL to use the full value as the index?

Answer (score 1):

I've tried your code on my local env and worked fine. I've tried insert this query first:

```
INSERT INTO `test`.`reset`
    (`id`,`identity_id`,`hash`,`timestamp`,`upn`,`returnurl`,`processed`,`referer`)
VALUES
    (
    null, 1, '4d9acbacc6ed7dc2733025e4b8af7be4940fe5b70338789b34caea27695860fa2b497f6cd34851657c9d3e8e8e88713d80da1a22d8654cf98622e9af3f29481t',
    null, 'a', null, null, null
    );
```

Which worked fine. Then I've tried insert the same query and got the same error as you:

```
Error Code: 1062. Duplicate entry '4d9acbacc6ed7dc2733025e4b8af7be4940fe5b70338789b34caea27695860fa' for key 'hash_UNIQUE'
```

Ok, here I've changed just the last character on the hash (b instead t) and then it worked fine:

```
INSERT INTO `test`.`reset`
    (`id`,`identity_id`,`hash`,`timestamp`,`upn`,`returnurl`,`processed`,`referer`)
VALUES
    (
    null, 1, '4d9acbacc6ed7dc2733025e4b8af7be4940fe5b70338789b34caea27695860fa2b497f6cd34851657c9d3e8e8e88713d80da1a22d8654cf98622e9af3f29481b',
    null, 'a', null, null, null
    );
```

Which means MySQL is using the full value for the UNIQUE index, even if it shows to you just part of your hash on the error report.

I could not find the reason why mysql does not show the whole string, however I believe your issue is definitely not related with a partial index use by the parser. Let me know how you go.

Comment: All my research states the same. A lot of people are getting stumped on this odd error.  But I had seen a bug report somewhere that stated the index size had been increased from 32 to 64 characters.  I'm wondering if it might have something to do with some version.  But I will try to test this separately when I get a chance.